# Highcharts-ng reset zoom

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I have this problem using highcharts-ng: when I try to push a new data series over an existing data series already in a chart, the new series will be zoomed with the old zoom. My question is: is there any way to zoom to the default value of the new series after it's loaded?

```
$scope.datChart.series.pop();    
$scope.datChart.series.push({data:dataArray, name:'Total'});
//$scope.datChart zoom out to default value of the new series
```

PS: the function zoomOut() doesn't work with highcharts-ng.

Thanks anyways

Comment: How about function `xAxis[0].setExtremes(null, null);` ?

Comment: every method that I try to call like this "$scope.projectPerMonth.xAxis[0].setExtremes(null, null);" doesn't work with angular

Comment: I see, then try to update `$scope.datChart.xAxis.min/max` with new min and max. I can see that watch is set for axes, like for series. Just a lucky guess.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. I found a way around by setting:

```
$scope.chart.xAxis.min = xMinValue; 
$scope.chart.xAxis.max = xMaxValue;
$scope.chart.xAxis.currentMin =  xMinValue; 
$scope.chart.xAxis.currentMax = xMaxValue;
```

so every time you push new data, you do it by **updating** these *$scopes* as well

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. All series keep the same zoom from the first series that I have pushed. If I console.log the currentMin and min they are correct for that series, although the charts keeps unchanged.

Comment: In the xAxis try:

events: { setExtremes: function(e){} }